# Not able to add udf in withcolumn in pyspark azure databricks

Tags: database, pyspark, azure-databricks

***User defined function***

```
def get_delakeys(charge_type):
        start=[]
        for index,row in lt_online.toPandas().iterrows():
            for i in charge_type:
                final = {"keyanme" : i,"value" : row[i],"description":".."}
                start.append(final)
            #final_val= {"value" : row['Charge_Type']}
    #start.append(final_val)
    return start

get_res_udf = f.udf(get_delakeys, MapType(StringType(),StringType()))
```

***udf call***

```
get_res_udf = f.udf(get_delakeys, MapType(StringType(),StringType()))
```

***Function test call***

```
get_delakeys(["Charge_Type"])
    output:
    [{'keyanme': 'Charge_Type', 'value': 'DET', 'description': '..'}
```

]

***When I call udf in dataframe thorows error***

```
df3=lt_online.withColumn("new_column",get_delakeys(col("Charge_Type")))
```

My requirement to pass more than one column in this function.
Error:
***Column is not iterable***

Comment: Lots of problems here:  What is the schema for your "Charge_Type" column? Looks like your udf expects an array of stringTypes.  Is that the case?  What is lt_online?  Your udf is returning an array of dicts, but you specify just a dict when you build with f.udf().

Comment: Passing a column to the function `get_delakeys()` and trying to loop through it is causing the error. Pyspark column is not iterable. Try passing a list of strings (column names) to get_delakeys() function and please provide the schema of `lt_online` dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of function
write following way

```
df=lt_online.withColumn("new_column",lit(''))
start=[]
dealkeys=["Charge_Type","Direction"]
for index,row in lt_online.toPandas().iterrows():

    key = row['Charge_No']
    for i in dealkeys:
        final = {"keyanme" : i,"value" : row[i],"description":".."}
        start.append(final)
    #final_val= {"value" : row['Charge_Type']}
#start.append(final_val)
#df3=lt_online.withColumn("new_column",str(start))
df3 = df.withColumn('new_column', when(col('Charge_No') == key , str(start)).otherwise(col('new_column')))
```

New_column will be stored as string

```
[{'keyanme': 'Charge_Type', 'value': 'DET', 'description': '..'},
 {'keyanme': 'Direction', 'value': 'IMP', 'description': '..'}]
```

Created schema for this

```
import json
dictionary = [{"Charge_Type": "DET", "Country": "VN", "Tariff_Loc": "VNSGN"}]
array_new = [ {'keyname' : i, 'value' : dictionary[i],'description' : "..."} for i in dict(dictionary)]
print(json.dumps(array_new))
array_new_1=json.dumps(array_new)
array_new_1
```

Called schema in dataframe level to change string to json.

```
df2_neww=df3.withColumn("NewColumn1", from_json(col("NewColumn1"), json_schema))



NewColumn1:array
 element:struct
    keyname:string
    value:string
    description:string
```